# Wraped C++ function for c# causes error

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to wrap the `_chdir()` function for use in my c# console app because I believe, unlike the available methods in c#, it changes the working directory after the app is closed, so it won't revert.*

Process: 

<sup>I'm including this since "Microsoft flavored" c++ seems to be a bit odd</sup>

In my solution with my c# application project I created a c++ class library project, and built my library:
*header file:*

```
// changeDir.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

//#define DllImport   __declspec( dllimport )
//#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

namespace changeDir {
    export "C"{
        class changeDir
        {
            public:
                    void changeDirectory(char * targetPath);
        };
    };
}
```

*ccp file:*

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "changeDir.h"

#include "direct.h"

namespace changeDir {
    void changeDir::changeDirectory(char * targetPath)
    {
        _chdir(targetPath);
    }
}
```

*c# file:*

```
//I'm including these incase I'm missing somthing
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Bookmarkable
{
    //Misc classes, not relevent
    class Program
    {

    //Functions including Main()

        [DllImport("changeDir.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
        public static extern void changeDirectory(string targetLocation);

        static void GoToLocation(string location = "")
        {
            //Code, don't worry, all the vars are defined :D!
            changeDirectory(targetLocation.Path);
        }
       //More functions
     }
}
```

I think I built a CLR type c++ project, I can't remember, and I don't know where to check...

This is all fine and dandy until i try to compile the c#, it gives this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'changeDirectory' in DLL 'changeDir.dll'.
```

After some research I tried to fix the problem by finding the exports using VS's dumpbin: this was the result:

```
File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .data
        9000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        3000 .rsrc
        3000 .text
```

No idea what that means...? is it even exporting?

**Things I've tried**

- DLLExport (see commented out lines... also added the name infront of the class)
- Export "C", still in the code...

**Questions**

1. Whats wrong?
2. How can I fix it?
3. Is there a better, easier way to fix this?

<sub>*Everything on this in c# said its not possible.... I'd really like to do it, please don't tell me I shouldn't be trying to do what I'm trying to do, I have my reasons!</sub>

Comment: You are wasting your time, `_chdir()` calls the SetCurrentDirectory() winapi function.  Just like the .NET does.  Your native DLL has no exports because you didn't use __declspec(dllexport).  And the code is wrong, you can't pinvoke an instance method of a C++ class.  It must be *static*.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there *any* way to change the current directory when using command line??? I really find it hard to believe that its impossible!

Comment: @HansPassant Could you explain that in more detail in an answer.... that is a bit cryptic as it stands